# Mp3 stream: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, mp3, audio-streaming

I want to use mp3 stream as an audio to video stream using ffmpeg.
Here is audio stream: http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/
It worked really well until today. I have no idea why it stopped working as audio stream seems to be fine (however I have no controll over it), but ffprobe cannot process it (Invalid data found when processing input).

Why it doesn't work anymore?
Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It works for me: `Input #0, mp3, from 'http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/': [...]  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 121 kb/s`. Maybe it was down momentarily for maintenance or something.

Comment: Any idea what may be wrong on my side?

Comment: Can it be something to do with firewall (or something network related)? No idea

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers for questions regarding programming. You might want to ask your question at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: It's not due to firewall as it recognize other streams. It is not due to downtime either. Do you think that I may have to recompile ffmpeg?